# Character Array Print in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

Here is the code I am using.

```
    int j=0;
    char v[] = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
    for(j=0;v[j]!='\0';j++)
        {
            cout << v[j] << "\n";   
        }
```

The "cout" line should technically only print the vowels.
But when I print it on VS code using the MSVC (compiler and debugger) ,it is giving me this unexpected output.
Thanks in advance!

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKGiN.png)

Comment: You need to explicitly add a `'\0'` to the array if your logic expects one to be there. If you initialized the array with a string literal it would be properly terminated but when initialized with individual characters it will not unless you do it yourself.

Comment: Alright well after I posted this question I found a solution to my own problem!!!
Which was I added a '\0' character to my char array and that fixed the print problem.
I guess for a character array you need to add this null character otherwise you might end up with undefined behaviour.
But this null character is not required when I am entering a string like example:
char s[] ={"Hello"};

Comment: `for(char ch : v) { cout << ch << '\n'; }` would be an alternative. There's very little risk of running out of bounds when using range-based `for` loops.

Comment: @DeatHerTZ - So you have discovered the difference between a character array and a string. By definition, a string is terminated by a `´\0'`, otherwise it is not a string. An array *might* hold a string, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
char v[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
```

This creates a `char[5]` named `v`.

```cpp
for (j = 0; v[j] != '\0'; j++)
```

Here the condition is that `v[j] != '\0'` but there is no `\0` in the array. `v[4]` is `'u'` and `v[5]` is out of bounds. Accessing `v[5]` (and beyond) makes the program have *undefined behavior* and it could print just about anything or crash - or do something worse.

Alternative solutions:

1. Use the size of the array to not go beyond the last element in it:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

int main() {   
    char v[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    for (std::size_t j = 0; j < std::size(v); j++) {
        std::cout << v[j] << '\n';
    }
}
```

2. Use a range-based `for` loop:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {   
    char v[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

    for (char ch : v) {
        std::cout << ch << '\n';
    }
}
```

3. Add a `'\0'` to the array, effectively making it a `char[6]` instead:

```cpp
char v[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0'};
// or simpler:
char v[] = "aeiou";
```

Comment: perhaps worth mentioning that if there was a null terminator as assumed by OP then `std::cout << v;` would work and no loop is needed

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Except that OP adds `'\n'` after each character :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you for the great explanation.
One more question is that If I initialize it as a string literal and I need to extract each character one by one. Does it actually make the range based for-loop invalid?
Also could you please explain "std:size_t".

Comment: @DeatHerTZ No, it doesn't make it invalid, but If you add a `'\0'` at the end, the range-based `for` loop will include that too.`std::size_t` is the unsigned integer type used for indexing. It's the same type you get from `sizeof` and `std::size()` etc.